# MVC3 search usercontrol

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a partial view in my website, shared among many pages, for searching functionality, consisting of:
from date
to date
file type
file name

now,the problem is, in some pages i dont want the **file type** to be included, in other pages i dont want the (**from-to**) date criteria to be included

what should i do? should i create a partial view for each functionality? or show/hide the criteria from within?

**_Filters.cshtml**

```
@model Entities.FilterOperations
<table width="85%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="formtit">
            Start Date
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "date" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="formtit">
            End Date
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "date" })
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td class="formtit">
            File Type
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileType)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="formtit">
            File Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileName)
        </td>
    </tr> <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a few properties to your FilterOperations model like:

```
public bool RenderFileType {get; private set;}
public bool RenderDateTo {get; private set;}
```

With a new ctor:

```
public FilterOperations(bool renderFileType = true, bool renderDateTo = true) {
    RenderFileType = renderFileType;
    RenderDateTo = renderDateTo;
}
```

Now you can set conditions in your partial like so:

```
@if(Model.RenderFileType) {
<tr>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileType)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Then in your view call your partial like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_Filters.cshtml", new FilterOperations(renderDateTo: false))
```

Comment: I don't think that's the best variant. In MVC pattern model is a data. No need to mix up business data with such properties for presentation. Viewdata and Viewbag are created for such cases.

Comment: How is it not data? It is just a property like IsActive or CanEdit. If you really want a separate your concerns, try something like this http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/asp-dot-net-mvc-viewmodel-usage-and-pick-your-best-pattern

Comment: Entitys are for business logic and to store data, DTO's are for transferring raw data, ViewModels are to help render a View and Commands are to receive data from Views. The above is a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

No sense to create almost equal partials. Use Viewbag.

```
@if(ViewBag.ShowSomething ?? true)
{
    //enter code here
}
```